# Remote Desktop connection issue on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm having issues connecting to my PC from my laptop on an internal network using Remote Desktop.

Here's the error message when I try to connect to my PC from my laptop:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMJqj.png]

However, I'm able to:

- Remote from my PC to my laptop (so remote desktop services running ok on both)
- Remote from my iPhone (using RD Client) to my PC on the same network (so PC is allowing RD)
- Remote from my laptop to an external VM (so there's nothing blocking outgoing RD connections on the laptop)

Laptop is running Windows 10 Pro 21H1, windows defender.
PC is running Windows 10 Pro 20H2, windows defender.

A few things I've tried:

- The PC account is logged in using Microsoft hotmail account, with a PIN setup.  I've tried swapping back to a local account, and trying different combinations of login names.  Most of my testing, I've not set a username, and waited for the prompt to enter a username.  I receive the error before I am prompted for a user name when connecting from my laptop, however this approached worked on other devices (PC and iPhone).
  I'm able to connect from iPhone using the Microsoft account to login.
- I've tried using either the hostname or the IP address for the PC, to no avail.
- I can telnet to [pc-name] 3389 ok from the laptop to the PC.
- I've tried a different client on the laptop - "Microsoft Remote Desktop" from the Microsoft Store.  With this I get the error "Error code: 0x4
  Extended error code: 0x0"
- Checked both firewalls allow Remote Desktop through

Which leaves me a bit stumped on what to look at next.  Any suggestions would be warmly welcomed! Thanks.

Comment: Further troubleshooting methods are listed in [article 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/troubleshoot/rdp-error-general-troubleshooting) and [article 2](https://techgenix.com/remote-desktop-cant-connect-to-the-remote-computer/).

Comment: Thanks @harrymc - followed as many of those as possible without luck.
Just seems odd that one client can connect and the other can't...

Comment: Which operating system are for the PC and laptop? Perhaps try to disable temporarily the firewall on the PC.

Comment: Both on Windows 10 Pro, but slight difference in version.  Disabled the firewall on PC, but still no luck :(

Comment: Try: (1) Disable also the antivirus on the PC, (2) In the PC registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server` set `MaxOutstandingConnections` to a high value such as 10000. If the value doesn't exist create it as DWORD 32-bit. Reboot. [source](https://serverfault.com/a/959180/18736).

Comment: @harrymc I've just tried both, unfortunately, still no luck. I really appreciate all your help :)

Comment: Update: I've just installed remote desktop onto mac, and I can connect to both PC and laptop fine.
I think the issue is with the laptop - I'm able to connect to an external RD computer outside the network, but cannot seem to connect inside the network.  Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: Very strange. Maybe something is wrong - try [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Indeed!  Nothing on sfc either.  I just started a windows 11 dual boot and I can remote fine from there on the laptop.  Sorry for anyone else that comes here looking for help!
@harrymc thanks for all your help